# How to import an svg document to a ThreeJS scene?

Tags: svg, three.js

I can see that there is a SVGLoader in the documentation, but it does not seem to be in r71. Do I have to compile master for this ?

Is there any other better way to achieve this ? Just looking for the best way to approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SVGLoader` can be found in the `examples/js` directory [here](http://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/examples/js/loaders).

You must include the loader source file explicitly in your project.

```
<script src="js/loaders/SVGLoader.js"></script>
```

three.js r.71